# Version Control for Wordpress or other solution for managing tons of Wordpress sites?

Tags: git, wordpress

I have a client who is managing 30+ Wordpress sites.  Each Wordpress install may have a different versions of Wordpress, different plugins, different plugins versions, different themes, etc.  It's all being managed via SFTP at the moment.

It's scary working without the safety net of version control.  Has anyone worked to wrangle Wordpress sites into Version Control?  It seems like there are two pieces:

- The actual WP install directory/along with it's wp-content folder.
- The MySQL DB that drives it.

I think I could live without getting the DB into version control, I'll just make sure it gets backed up frequently.

Has anyone done this?  What about hosting out of a private Github or BitBucket account?  Experience?

Comment: To me it sounds like you need a frequent backup in place, and not a version control system, as there is no source code here that is being changed. Can you explain why would you want to use source control for this instead of backups?

Comment: I think he wants to be able to bulk update 30+ wordpress installations (or just have a much better way of managing so many different installations, without having to go to each one and update each one manually). I mean the wrench in trying to do that is having incompatible plugins across 30+ different sites. It's still an interesting problem though, I don't know how to approach this yet.

Comment: Im also a little confused as to what you are asking for.  Are you looking for a way to push Wordpress core and plugin updates to your sites from a central location or are you simply looking for disaster recovery across all 30 sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company i work for has roughly the same setups we have around 80 word press installs two are multi site installs with 3-4 under that for our versioning we use git and have disabled ftp access to the boxes to force git usage for deployment which helps a lot when trying to keep up with all the changes as for the databases we have some scripts that dump the db's to a network drive in the company.

Hope that helps with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution (but it will take some time and effort to implement) would be to move all of the sites into a WordPress multisite setup.

There are a lot of places to get step-by-step instructions on this but WordPress itself has a pretty good explanation of what you need to do: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

I'm running a multisite setup for quite a few of my freelance clients and it's great. They all run from one WordPress core so you only need to update that. They can all have their own plugins and, of course, plugins that are not being used across the network will need to be updated individually for the sites that use them.

I'm also running one big WordPress site using Subversion which is awesome. However, it's not necessarily a good solution for trying to wrangle with 30+ sites.